# Weak Law Of Large Numbers without assumption of having finite variance

Tags: probability, probability-theory, law-of-large-numbers

In the first volume of Feller's book ([see at Archive](https://archive.org/details/AnIntroductionToProbabilityTheoryAndItsApplicationsVolume1/page/n249)), chapter 10  section 2, there is a proof of the weak law of large numbers for the case the second moment does not exist.

I am reading about 7 books in English and Russian and none goes further than using Chebyshev's Inequality and assuming existence of the first two moments. Wikipedia and just googling for a proof without variance do not help to find it either.

Does anyone know why such a beautiful and, moreover, much general proof is so unpopular? Or, maybe there is some imperfection I do not notice, could you point it out? Thank you!

Comment: I did not know this proof myself and I found it rather beautiful, and I also believe it is correct. I think the reason for this proof not being standard in courses/books is conciseness. The proof of the weak LLN with the assumption of $var X <\infty$ is short, and without the assumption, one already needs to prove the strong version of the LLN, so this version is not necessary.

Comment: @Kernel indeed, even on the Wiki page it's said: "Large or infinite variance will make the convergence slower, but the LLN holds anyway. This assumption is often used because it makes the proofs easier and shorter." However, Feller proves all sides of both the weak and strong laws. So, let's consider it to be just another reason why Feller's book is a must read for any topic lover :) Thank you!